# usb-creator-gtk doesn't find my virtual disk. What's wrong?

Tags: usb-creator

I know how to create a USB stick allowing installation of Ubuntu, but now I'd like to do some tests with usb-creator. And instead of making useless writings onto my USB stick, I wanted to see how usb-creator-gtk works on a "virtual disk-partition".

The trouble is that when I launch usb-creator-gtk, it finds my /dev/sdb2 (*REAL* USB formatted as FAT32) but NOT any virtual disk that I made. And I have no idea why.
I suppose that usb-creator-gtk has a way to recognize USB stick devices, but I don't know how to trick it.

Here is what I did to create my virtual disk:

```
 mkdir /tmp/t7; cd /tmp/t7
 dd if=/dev/null of=vu7 bs=1 seek=3800M count=0
 losetup /dev/loop7 vu7
 sfdisk -uM /dev/loop7 << EOF
 > 10,3000,c,*
 >;
 > EOF
 fdisk -l /dev/loop7
 # Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
 # /dev/loop7p1   *       16065     6168959     3076447+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
 # /dev/loop7p2               1       16064        8032   83  Linux
 mknod /dev/loop7p1 b 7 8
 losetup /dev/loop7p1 -o $((512 * 16065)) --sizelimit $(((6168959-16065)*512)) vu7
 mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/loop7p1
 # --> mkfs.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
 # --> Loop device does not match a floppy size, using default hd params
 install-mbr /dev/loop7
 partprobe /dev/loop7
 partprobe /dev/loop7p1
```

but in the end usb-creator-gtk completly ignores my loop7p1 device.

Answer (score 0):

This is a process that is not worth the effort and will require a bunch more things to be done, before getting any progress to be done.  Your goal is to install a Live CD on a logical partition of a "removable Media" item.  This requires a large amount of time that even my Chief network analyst said it require more time than is worth putting in.